# ampvis2 change order of color sample_color_order = NULL

Tags: colors

I am trying to change the order of colors in an ordination. I know that I have to use sample_color_order : Order the colors in sample_color_by by the order in a vector. But I can't find a way to refer to my vector (data is an ampvis2 object built from a phyloseq). All examples I found are with NULL. I would appreciate your help.

```
amp_ordinate(
 data = data,
 distmeasure = "bray",
 filter_species = 0,
 type = "NMDS",
 transform = "none",
 sample_color_by = "Treatment",
 sample_colorframe = TRUE,
 sample_label_by =  "Codigo",
 sample_shape_by = "Country",
 sample_point_size = 3,
 species_label_taxonomy = "Species",
 sample_color_order = NULL)
```